# Android - Creating your own calendar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, sdk

Is there away of creating a calendar app for android from scratch using java and xml in eclipse or is there an already made calendar.

Comment: what do you mean, there are lots of calendar apps plus the ones that exist on the phone and tablet which have been written in java already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Calendar is simply a table, which you can create in Android.  A TextView on top can be used for the current month.  Clicking on a cell can open the list of events for that day.

Comment: how can one make it so it changes as the days pass

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two ways to "create your own calendar".
The easy way is to create a client of google calendar or other service.
And the second is to create a client and server of your calendar.